# Two columns with alternate colors with CSS

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to create a 2 columns grid with alternate colors (first cell red, the second yellow, the third yellow, the fourth red and so on)

Using a 3 cols grid I've no problem, but with this layout I'm gonna crazy =_=

Could someone help me?

Thanks

brk

Comment: can you share a code or fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this selector `:nth-child()`:

```
/*Every 2 rows from 0 (even) - Every 2 cells from 0 (even)*/
.row:nth-child(2n+0) div:nth-child(2n+0) { 
    background: #ff0000;
}

/*Every 2 rows from 0 (even) - Every 2 cells from 1 (odd)*/
.row:nth-child(2n+0) div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #ffff00;
}

/*Every 2 rows from 1 (odd) - Every 2 cells from 0 (even)*/
.row:nth-child(2n+1) div:nth-child(2n+0) {
    background: #ffff00;
}

/*Every 2 rows from 1 (odd) - Every 2 cells from 1 (odd)*/
.row:nth-child(2n+1) div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

> [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0tyz9uaw/)

Which can be simplified like this :

```
.row:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
.row:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ffff00;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) div:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ffff00;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

> [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/trkwb0rp/)

---

> [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using css grid layout with two columns you can't use rows, but you can use this snippet:

```css
div:first-child, 
div:nth-child(4n), 
div:nth-child(4n+1) {
 background-color: #f00;
}
```